# How to extract data in Map<String,Integer> from JSONArray

Tags: android

I have array ( JSONArray object ) with values  like

```
[["one",1],["two",2],["three",3]...]
```

How to extract this to Map ?
I can get single JSONObject from array but how to extract from that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
myMap.put(myJsonObject.getString(keyOfStringValueInJson), myJsonObject.getInt(keyOfIntValueInJson));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Refer](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/)

```
try {
        JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) jArr.get(0);
        int data = jobj.getInt("one");
    } catch (JSONException e) {}
```